# Groovy module is not loaded when creating Elasticsearch 5 Node in Java code

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm currently trying to migrate an application from using ES 1.7 to ES 5.4. While the migration of the actual application is pretty smooth, the tests are a pain. The problem are lots of Groovy scripts in the aggregations. To test those, an Elasticsearch Node is constructed via Java code. That works fine for ES 1.7, but throws exceptions for ES 5.4. The node is constructed like this:

```
final Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("transport.type", "local")
            .put("http.enabled", "false")
            .put("cluster.name", "integration-test-cluster")
            .put("path.home", DEFAULT_ES_DIRECTORY)
            .put("path.data", DEFAULT_DATA_DIRECTORY)
            .put("path.logs", DEFAULT_LOGS_DIRECTORY)
            .put("script.inline", "true")
            .put("script.file", "true")
            .put("script.legacy.default_lang", "groovy")
return new Node(elasticsearchSettings.build()).start();
```

I added groovy-lang (2.4.5) as dependency as well as groovy-all. But when I then pass a Groovy script in an aggregation, the test fails with an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.getScriptEngineServiceForLang(ScriptService.java:187)
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:259)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.getLazySearchScript(QueryShardContext.java:353)
```

When I turn on logging for this Elasticsearch node, I see that the Groovy module is not even loaded:

```
[INFO ] 2017-05-23 16:39:42.857 [main] PluginsService - no modules loaded
[INFO ] 2017-05-23 16:39:42.857 [main] PluginsService - no plugins loaded
```

I tried to force the loading of that module by adding a "modules" file in the directory Elasticsearch will run (the one defined in DEFAULT_ES_DIRECTORY) with just "lang-groovy" in it, but that just results in a different exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize modules
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:426)
at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getModuleBundles(PluginsService.java:270)
at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:116)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:242)
```

I tried to use the constructor that uses the classpathPlugins as parameters and pass the GroovyPlugin.class from groovy-lang, but, as you might have guessed, all I get is an exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyPlugin overrides final method onModule.(Lorg/elasticsearch/script/ScriptModule;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

So how can I activate Groovy scripts for that node?